# With a passport missing two pages can I still apply for visas?

Tags: visas, passports, legal

My son cut two pages from my passport.

Will it be a problem if I apply for any visa and my passport has lost two pages?

Can I get refused for that reason?

It doesn't appear on it that any papers are lost.

Should I get a new one?

I will go to the embassy in two days and I don't have enough time!

Comment: What do you mean by “two papers”? Ripping apart two pages? A small cut on two pages?

Comment: By any strange coincidence would these be the pages containing a fraudulent application history your other question is about?  Just asking...

Comment: "It doesn't appear on it that any papers lost": aren't the pages numbered?  Usually they are, and in some passports there is a note along the lines of "this passport contains N pages" so one can tell whether pages were removed from the end.

Comment: @pnuts via the perforations?

Comment: @pnuts interesting, my older US passports (from the 70s) had that, but not the newer ones.  But these perforations wouldn't help identify missing pages, would they?

Comment: @phoog, the OP is trying to say that the offending page was removed and then the corresponding leaf opposite the stitching was removed so that when the passport is closed it looks symmetrical and there's no loose page in the quarto.  Two papers...  In a British passport, pages 14 and 19 for example

Comment: @pnuts there are page numbers shown here: http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-1306018/New-UK-passport-design-unveiled-Sundials-narrow-boats-windmills.html; do you have a different model?  Also: http://prado.consilium.europa.eu/en/8365/docHome.html#docelement7

Comment: @GayotFow even if the pages were removed as you describe, examination of the page numbers would reveal that the pages were removed.

Comment: @phoog, they don't need to count the pages. You can tell just from opening the passport that the stitching is buggered. Any doubts then look at the seam in the middle page.  Counting pages is for wimps :)

Comment: @GayotFow sure.  I was looking, however, for a more objective line of reasoning to suggest that it is unrealistic to believe that "it doesn't appear on it that any pages lost."

Comment: @GayotFow is that question deleted now? I can’t find anything fraudulent in the only other question I see of this person, only that he may have applied for the wrong visa.

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek GayotFow is no longer available, as he died during the summer. However, he was quite a contributer and it is very likely that he did look at OP's other questions, as reflected in the comment.

Comment: @Giorgio sad to hear that, thanks. Don’t know how this ended up in my feed considering it’s 3 years old.

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek they seem to pop up when we've participated in a question and/or answer, and someone comes along and either adds to it, often with a new 'answer' ... that is actually a question and it gets deleted.

Answer (score 16):

Most countries will consider a damaged passport invalid and require it to be replaced.

For instance, the [United States says](http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/english/passports/FAQs.html):

> If your passport has been significantly damaged, especially the book cover or the page displaying your personal data and photo, you will need to apply for a new passport.  Conditions that may constitute damage requiring you to replace your passport include water damage, a significant tear, unofficial markings on the data page, missing visa pages (torn out), a hole punch, or other injuries.

You will need to obtain a replacement passport.

But if there are still valid visas in your existing passport, you should keep it, and contact the consulates of those countries for further information after you obtain the new passport, as your old visas may still be valid even in the damaged passport, or they may require you to transfer them to the new passport.